# Select duplicate users in SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey there I searched a lot but cant find a answer.

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user.originalID` != `user.fakeID`
```

this is only an example but all 2 id´s are in the same table cant find a solution seems easy but stress a lot :(

lets say we know that the guy with id 1 have an 2nd accout with id 9000 so i give him the fake id 9000 to identify him. Now I want to list all users on my list without the fake ones any one know  a solution ?

```
orginalID  fakeID  firstName   lastName
1            900     max        muster
2            null    John       Html
900          null    max        muster
```

SO i wannt to list all user but only the Orginal ones. All fake ones should not be listet.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What ? Could anyone explain what is asked here ????

Comment: Please don't edit your question with the solution.  Instead, accept the answer that worked for you by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a simple LEFT OUTER JOIN, and then check for no match

```
SELECT u1.* 
FROM user u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u2
ON u1.originalID = u2.fakeID
WHERE u2.fakeID IS NULL
```

Comment: Worked ty you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM `user` u
WHERE u.originalID NOT IN (SELECT u2.fakeID FROM users u2 WHERE u2.fakeID IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would work without join also :

SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE orginalID not in (select fakeID from user where fakeID<>'NULL')